# SugarCRM Adding Additional Details Info icon in Detail View

Tags: sugarcrm

in SugarCRM some modules like "Calls" has an "i" (Additional Details) icon in List view which shows some additional details about that record.

I want to display same kind for other modules like customer visits with some custom details of the records.
  Any hints or guidance will be helpful.

Comment: I can see `i` icon on Listview but not able to find it in Detail View (even in Calls module ). Are you sure its Detail View ??

Comment: @ajay, suvera is right you just have to replace {MODULE_NAME} and  {MODULE_BEAN_NAME} with your module name and class for example your module name is Customers and bean name is Customer than function name will be `additionalDetailsCustomer` for more idea on this. please see sugarcrm_installation/modules/Calls/metadata/additionalDetails.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Create a file in your metadata folder `{MODULENAME}/metadata/additionalDetails.php`. You have to find correct place of your module.

- custom/modules/MODULENAME/metadata/
- custom/modulebuilder/packages/PACKAGENAME/modules/MODULENAME/metadata/
- etc...

2) and create a function something like this. replace `{MODULENAME}` and `{MODULE_BEAN_NAME}` with actual module name in all places.

```
function additionalDetails{MODULE_BEAN_NAME}($fields) {
    static $mod_strings;
    if(empty($mod_strings)) {
        global $current_language;
        $mod_strings = return_module_language($current_language, '{MODULENAME}');
    }

    $overlib_string = '';

    if(!empty($fields['NAME']))
        $overlib_string .= '<b>'. $mod_strings['LBL_NAME'] . '</b> ' . $fields['NAME'] . ' <br>';

    //Add whatever info you want to show up to $overlib_string

    $editLink = "index.php?action=EditView&module={MODULENAME}&record={$fields['ID']}";
    $viewLink = "index.php?action=DetailView&module={MODULENAME}&record={$fields['ID']}";

    return array(
        'fieldToAddTo' => 'NAME',
        'string' => $overlib_string,
        'editLink' => $editLink,
        'viewLink' => $viewLink
    );
}
```

you have to create `$overlib_string` with your data (in html). If you need edit and view links on your modal box you have to return them as well.  `$fields` is an associative array that contains db record.

3) The `i` icon should appear on the module list view.